# Processing and Mosaic Sentinel 2 Data with Python

Tags: python, sentinel-2, image-mosaic

I already found this manual for processing Sentinel-2 Data:
https://hatarilabs.com/ih-en/sentinel2-images-explotarion-and-processing-with-python-and-rasterio

Now I'm searching for a way to mosaic overlapping Sentinel-2 Data with Python, to create a single GeoTIFF.

Comment: For ideas on starting code perhaps review https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sentinel-2+python